# How to disable the manual deployment of an App service from Visual studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

How to disable the manual deployment (i.e. via publish profile) of an App service from Visual studio and always make sure that the deployment to an App service happens only via CI/CD pipeline from Azure DevOps

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding an Networking Rule on the -SCM part of the appService.

In the portal, go to your appservice, and go to networking.
In the Features box, click on acces Restrictions.

[image]

Switch to the {YourApp}-scm rules. Add a rule to allow the  AzureCloud service. This will allow your pipelines to publish the app, but publishing from all other places will be blocked.

Please not that Advanced Tools (Kudu) will also be blocked because of this rule.

Answer (score -1):

By reference to this doc: [Publish a Web app to Azure App Service using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-azure?view=vs-2019),

[image]

And you could refer to this doc: [Azure Pipelines ecosystem support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/ecosystems?view=azure-devops) to build and deploy your apps. For example, you could follow this tutorial: [Deploy PHP application to Azure App Service using Azure Pipelines](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/php/). Also you could use tool: [DevOps Starter and Azure DevOps integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/overview#devops-starter-and-azure-devops-integration).